# How to Authorize and call slack methods from a Cron?

Tags: php, api, slack-api

I'm trying to call `users.list` and `channel.invite` from a PHP `cron` file.
How can i authorize to get token in this case.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to get an access token for your script:

**Install app via admin window**

Create a Slack app and install it via the admin window in Slack. This will also give you an access token, which you can then use in your PHP cron script. You find the admin window to create and configure your apps under "Your apps" on the [API documentation page](https://api.slack.com/).

**Install app via custom script**

Create a Slack app and a web page and run through the [oauth process](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) to get an access token for a user. This is the standard method for most Slack apps. The oauth process has to be run once only and your web page / script should store the resulting access token (e.g. in a file), which you can then use for your PHP cron job.

**Legacy Tokens**

This gives you a general token with rights based on your user account in Slack, which you can use with any API method. Its an easy and quick way, but was only ever meant for testing and development and is now out-dated. The process is now called [Legacy Tokens](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens).

**Conclusion**

I would recommend the first approach (install via admin window) for your case. Please also make sure that you request the [scopes](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes) needed for the mentioned API methods during installation.